# change script content without page reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script id='sc' src="index.js"></script>
```

**index.js**

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    console.log('lorem');
});
```

now I have jquery ajax code for changing `index.js` content, to be like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    console.log('ipsum');
});
```

// reload `index.js`

```
$(sc).attr('src', 'index.js');
```

but click on button is still - `lorem`
after reloading the page it is `ipsum`

is there a way to get this without page reloading?

Comment: Hard refresh page to load the changes of the js file then check again

Comment: it will work with ctrl+F5 in windows

Comment: index.js has been cached on your browser.

Comment: @MunawarHussian - pls read the last sentence of the post again

Comment: If you explain what type of content you want to change without page reloading this type of change means you are updating the index.js file and then you need changes without loading actually code and content is two different thing

Comment: @RakibulIslam - but `$(sc).attr('src', 'index.js');` should cache the new content, isn't it?

Comment: @Lety - thanks, but `62` answers and mainly discussions and not a solution for my scenario

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Replacing the src so it brings in different js won't remove the js that previously was loaded. If original code added an event listener, that even listener will still be attached to the element

Comment: @Lety - yes, the new script is in dom, but click is still resulting in `lorem`. Only after reloading the page it works

Comment: I tested it and finally think that @charlietfl is right. you probably can't update script already loaded, even adding version doesn't work. I can see that element is changed, but it still loaded in the main thread. There is a lot of questions about your question, may be you'll be more lucky than me.